# Flat tyre usage

Tags: sentence-construction

How to say this sentence in a more natural way?

" Bicycle tyres are more susceptible to getting flat"

"Bicycle  tend to get more flat tyres compared to cars"

It sounds awkward when I say them out loud.

Any better options?

Comment: Bicycle tyres go flat more often than car tyres.

Comment: Have you considered using the word "punctures"?  In my experience, bike tyres very rarely go flat, unless they are punctured.